# System.LimitException: ivybat:Too many SOQL queries: 101 - Stack Trace

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits, limitexception, stacktrace

I am getting this error as my unit test are failing and in the stack trace getting class names which are not related to my test class. Object name is also appended in the error, the object name is ivybat.

Need help in understanding why the object name is appended in the error and why I am seeing different classes in stack trace which are not related to my test class.

below is the error and stack trace :

Error :  `System.LimitException: ivybat:Too many SOQL queries: 101`

Stack trace :

```
Class.ivybat.CommonUtility.getParentRecord: line 600, column 1
Class.ivybat.CommonUtility.updateMarketISOFromParent: line 638, column 1
Class.ivybat.territoryStoreMappingTriggerHandler.updateMarketIso: line 188, column 1
Trigger.ivybat.territoryStoreMappingTrigger: line 34, column 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This failure is in a managed package with the namespace `ivybat`. The managed package is installed in your org.

You can't debug managed package code, although you may be able to guess your way to a solution, such as reducing record volume that causes this trigger to run.

You should contact the vendor for assistance. They're the only ones who can provide a true solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per David Reed's answer, the issue is reported against processing in the ivybat managed package and you cannot debug that - only the supplier of the package can.

However, the issues could, in principle, be caused by the subscriber org configuration. For example, badly written flows without guards that repeatedly update records for object types that are part of rthis managed package.

As an ISV developer, I find it frustrating when subscribers immediately conclude that the problem is in the package, simply because the limit is hit in some automation in the package. The whole platform's behaviour must be considered before deciding the likely source of issue by performing some analysis using the Developer Console.

I recommend using the Log Analyser against an appropriate log captured showing this issue. Access it through the developer console's Debug menu's change perspective. Look out for repeated initiation of a flow or similar subscriber org automation before contacting the package provider for help.